# error while deploying a spring application on WebSphere

Tags: spring, deployment, websphere, ibm-rad

I am getting the below errors on the server console while deploying a spring application on websphere.

Seeing these errors for the first time. So no idea about head and tail about these errors.

```
    [10/13/11 12:12:33:820 IST] 00000024 FileRepositor A   ADMR0009I: Document cells/A3564XDZYCJLQZHNode01Cell/applications/SecurityMaster_App.ear/deployments/SecurityMaster_App/deployment.xml is created.
[10/13/11 12:12:33:820 IST] 00000024 FileRepositor A   ADMR0010I: Document cells/A3564XDZYCJLQZHNode01Cell/nodes/A3564XDZYCJLQZHNode01/serverindex.xml is modified.
[10/13/11 12:12:34:352 IST] 0000001e ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: SecurityMaster_App
[10/13/11 12:12:34:352 IST] 0000001e ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: SecurityMaster_App  Application build level: Unknown
[10/13/11 12:12:34:430 IST] 0000001e WebGroup      A   SRVE0169I: Loading Web Module: SecurityMaster.
[10/13/11 12:12:34:477 IST] 0000001e ResourceProce E   CWNEN0017E: The injection engine cannot resolve the target of the ADAMServiceUrl resource-ref declaration to the associated binding location in the global namespace.
[10/13/11 12:12:34:492 IST] 0000001e ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl initialize FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_0000001e_11.10.13_12.12.34_0.txt
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_0000001e_11.10.13_12.12.34_0.txt
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e InjectionEngi E   CWNEN0011E:  The injection engine failed to process bindings for the metadata.
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl open FFDC0009I: FFDC opened incident stream file C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_0000001e_11.10.13_12.12.34_1.txt
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e ServiceLogger I com.ibm.ws.ffdc.IncidentStreamImpl resetIncidentStream FFDC0010I: FFDC closed incident stream file C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\ffdc\server1_0000001e_11.10.13_12.12.34_1.txt
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e ComponentName E   CNTR0125E: Unable to process injection information for class: [class uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet, class com.hsbc.gpb.uno.sm.security.processor.SecurityServlet, class com.hsbc.esf.requestprocessing.servlet.impl.ServletFrontController, class org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter, class com.hsbc.esf.logging.web.impl.LoggingManagementContextListener, class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener].
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e WebApp        E   Error occured while populating the namespace 
com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: Failed to process bindings for metadata
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionEngineImpl.processBindings(InjectionEngineImpl.java:415)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(InjectionEngineImpl.java:268)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:503)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: The injection engine cannot resolve the target of the ADAMServiceUrl resource-ref declaration to the associated binding location in the global namespace.
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.ResourceProcessor.resolve(ResourceProcessor.java:616)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.collectInjectionNBindingData(InjectionProcessor.java:641)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.InjectionEngineImpl.processBindings(InjectionEngineImpl.java:406)
    ... 52 more

[10/13/11 12:12:34:758 IST] 0000001e LoggingManage I com.hsbc.esf.logging.web.impl.LoggingManagementContextListener loggingInitalization ES Logging initialized.
[10/13/11 12:12:34:758 IST] 0000001e WebApp        A   SRVE0180I: [SecurityMaster_App#SecurityMaster.war] [/SecurityMaster] [Servlet.LOG]: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[10/13/11 12:12:34:758 IST] 0000001e ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[10/13/11 12:12:34:789 IST] 0000001e XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@71347134: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Thu Oct 13 12:12:34 IST 2011]; root of context hierarchy
[10/13/11 12:12:34:867 IST] 0000001e XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/services.xml]
[10/13/11 12:12:34:945 IST] 0000001e XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@71347134]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@20802080
[10/13/11 12:12:34:992 IST] 0000001e DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@20802080: defining beans [loginService,loginDAO,ssoTokenDAO,securityWebService,webServiceLocator,securityMasterConfigLocator]; root of factory hierarchy
[10/13/11 12:12:35:039 IST] 0000001e ContextLoader I org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 281 ms
[10/13/11 12:12:35:055 IST] 0000001e WebApp        A   SRVE0180I: [SecurityMaster_App#SecurityMaster.war] [/SecurityMaster] [Servlet.LOG]: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'SecurityMaster'
[10/13/11 12:12:35:055 IST] 0000001e ServletFrontC I org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'SecurityMaster': initialization started
[10/13/11 12:12:35:055 IST] 0000001e XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@77187718: display name [WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SecurityMaster-servlet']; startup date [Thu Oct 13 12:12:35 IST 2011]; parent: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@71347134
[10/13/11 12:12:35:055 IST] 0000001e XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SecurityMaster-servlet.xml]
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 6.1 [EJB3 6.1.0.19 cf190834.03] [BASE 6.1.0.19 cf190836.04] [WEB2FEP 1.0.0.1 web20835.6] [WEBSERVICES 6.1.0.19 cf190834.03]  running with process name A3564XDZYCJLQZHNode01Cell\A3564XDZYCJLQZHNode01\server1 and process id 2884
Host Operating System is Windows XP, version 5.1 build 2600 Service Pack 3
Java version = J2RE 1.5.0 IBM J9 2.3 Windows XP x86-32 j9vmwi3223ifx-20080811 (JIT enabled)
J9VM - 20080809_21892_lHdSMr
JIT  - 20080620_1845_r8
GC   - 200806_19, Java Compiler = j9jit23, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61
user.install.root = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1
Java Home = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/java/lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1/classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/classes;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/installedChannels;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/web/help;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1/properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/properties;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/startup.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/j2ee.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\bin;.;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files\1E\SMSNomad\;C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes\;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\Program Files\MKS\IntegrityClient\bin;C:\Program Files\SafeCom\SafeComPrintClient;C:\apache-maven-2.0.10\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\java\bin;;C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\lib\WMQ\java\lib
************* End Display Current Environment *************
i.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
    ... 87 more

[10/13/11 12:12:35:539 IST] 0000001e WrappingFileO W  switchFiles TRAS0031W: Unable to rename file C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\server1\SystemOut.log to C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\was61profile1\logs\server1\SystemOut_11.10.13_12.12.35.log during log file rollover. Attempting to copy file contents.
[10/13/11 12:12:35:539 IST] 0000001e ServletWrappe E   Deregister the mbean because of uncaught init() exception thrown by servlet SecurityMaster: javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception thrown by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1165)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:160)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:621)
    ---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SecurityMaster-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DynamicMetaDataImpl.invoke(DynamicMetaDataImpl.java:231)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
    ... 87 more
, 
[10/13/11 12:12:35:539 IST] 0000001e WebExtensionP E   Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization. 
javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception thrown by servlet
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:272)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:328)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1252)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:161)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:474)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:503)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:config.xml]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SecurityMaster-servlet.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:337)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:157)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:666)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:611)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1304)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4104)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:160)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:621)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:474)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:503)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1571)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2703)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2577)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1473)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:201)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:174)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.hsbc.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
    ... 87 more

[10/13/11 12:12:35:555 IST] 0000001e ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [SecurityMaster_App] [/SecurityMaster] [SecurityServlet]: Initialization successful.
[10/13/11 12:12:35:555 IST] 0000001e Logger        I uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput info Logging using commons-logging.
[10/13/11 12:12:35:586 IST] 0000001e DefaultConfig I uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput info Missing class for converter 'jdom'. Failed to load uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.convert.JDOMConverter. Cause: org.jdom.Document
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e DefaultConver I uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput info Can't marshall org.jdom.Document because converter 'jdom' is not available. The converter definition may be missing, or required element may be missing from the CLASSPATH
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e DefaultConver I uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput info Can't marshall org.jdom.Element because converter 'jdom' is not available. The converter definition may be missing, or required element may be missing from the CLASSPATH
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e LogErrorHandl E uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput error Line=2 Document root element "dwr", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e LogErrorHandl E uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.util.CommonsLoggingOutput error Line=2 Document is invalid: no grammar found.
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e ServletWrappe I   SRVE0242I: [SecurityMaster_App] [/SecurityMaster] [dwr-invoker]: Initialization successful.
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e VirtualHost   I   SRVE0250I: Web Module SecurityMaster has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].
[10/13/11 12:12:35:602 IST] 0000001e ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: SecurityMaster_App
```

Any help:

Basically about the following specific errors:

What does this signify ? what is the solution or approach towards solving it ?

```
[10/13/11 12:12:34:508 IST] 0000001e ComponentName E   CNTR0125E: Unable to process injection information for class: [class uk.ltd.getahead.dwr.DWRServlet, class com.infosys.gpb.uno.sm.security.processor.SecurityServlet, class com.infosys.esf.requestprocessing.servlet.impl.ServletFrontController, class org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter, class com.infosys.esf.logging.web.impl.LoggingManagementContextListener, class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener].
```

Also this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [interceptor-chain.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [config.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.infosys.com/schema/esrps-1.0.0]
Offending resource: class path resource [interceptor-chain.xml]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it could be the relevant root cause to me:

```
[10/13/11 12:12:34:477 IST] 0000001e ResourceProce E   CWNEN0017E: The injection engine cannot resolve the target of the ADAMServiceUrl resource-ref declaration to the associated binding location in the global namespace.
```

Are you using a JNDI `resource-ref` in your Spring config, and do you have a matching definition in your `web.xml` (and IBM-specific `.xmi` files if you deploy those in your WAR)?

Answer (score 0):

The CNTR0125E is reporting the issue expanded upon by the following "WebApp" message.  The message means you're missing a resource-ref binding in ibm-web-bnd for the "ADAMServiceUrl" for the corresponding resource-ref in web.xml.

I don't know what the Spring error means.